# Key refused WinSCP/PuTTY issue when connecting to Windows OpenSSH server

Tags: windows, putty, openssh, winscp, private-key

I'm trying to configure a private key for use use with WinSCP and PuTTY/Plink but I'm stuck (trying to connect from Windows 10 to Windows 2012 Server).

I have OpenSSH installed on my windows server and I can use a username and password to connect via WinSCP (SFTP) and PuTTY (SSH-2), but when I try to use a private key I get a key refused error.

I created the key on the local machine using PuTTYgen (RSA 2048) and added it to the server's `authorized_keys` file (I used the feature in WinSCP to do this automatically) for my user (not a local admin) in the same location as specified in the `sshd_config` file (`C:\Users\<username>\.ssh`).

I removed all permissions for all other accounts on this folder and the `authorized_keys` file.  I tried setting the logging to verbose on the server but there doesn't seem to be much to go on, just "Failed none" followed by "Failed publickey".

I don't know what else to try.  Does anyone else have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my openssh logfile didn't have anything useful in it because I had read to change the logging level in `C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\sshd_config` to **VERBOSE**, but that didn't provide all of the information I needed. It turns out that you have to change it to **DEBUG3**.
Now when I tried to use the key to connect I see this:

> 148 09:35:57:393 debug1: Could not open authorized keys 'C:\Users\sshuser\.ssh/authorized_keys': Permission denied

Which led me to this github comment specific to windows:  https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/826#issuecomment-318128066

Which indicated that the `NT SERVICE\sshd  account needs` to have read permissions on the `C:\Users\sshuser\.ssh/authorized_keys` folder and file for the user I was trying to connect with.  In my case, even Read & Execute was too much. You can only set read permission for sshd.

Comment: To change the debug level, find sshd_config file and:

Uncomment and change the values from:
 
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO
 
To:
 
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel DEBUG3

Comment: Note that the account that needs the read permissions is the account that runs the *"OpenSSH SSH service"*. It can be a different one than the `sshd`. In my case OpenSSH runs under the `SYSTEM` account. I've summarized this in my article about [Setting up SSH public key authentication of Windows OpenSSH server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server#key_authentication).